# emberjs model reverse relationship unclear

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a `postal_address` model that includes: street, zipcode, city, etc. I then have multiple unrelated models like **organization** or **user** that have the `postal_address` as one of their attributes. The using-models simply refer to the `postal_address` as `belongsTo`, specifying the reverse is not clear to me, i.e. inside of the `postal_address` do I indicate anything in terms of models that refer to it?

Depending on the context, updating the address may affect the Organization, other times the User. There are many more models that could use the `postal_address` than the two I listed, in the event one suggests to duplicate the address-model per use-case.

Answer (score 2):

> do I indicate anything in terms of models that refer to it?

no. only if you need to find all things that use an `postal_address` this direction is needed.

Comment: I then run into this which helped me arrive at the same conclusion - thanks of course! https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/976